The asymptotics of binomial $\binom{n}{cn}$, $c\in(0,1)$
From the book Asymptopia, page 64, we know that if $k\sim cn$, $c\in(0,1)$ then
$$\binom{n}{cn}=2^{n(H(c)+o(1))}$$
where $H(c):=-c\log_{10}(c)-(1-c)\log_{10}(1-c)$.
Now I use this formula to derive the following asymptotics:
Since $\log \big(2\binom{n}{cn}\big)=\big(nH(c)+o(n)\big)\log 2+\log 2$, we have
$$\frac{\log 2\binom{n}{cn}}{n}=\big(H(c)+o(1)+1/n\big)\log 2\rightarrow H(c)\log 2$$
But from numerics (Mathematica), it doesn't converge to $H(c)\log 2$, what could be wrong?
Here are the code and result:
c=0.5;Limit[Log[2 Binomial[n,c n]]/n,n->Infinity]
Out:=0.693147 

where $H(c)\log 2=0.208658$ for $c=0.5$.

@MarkViola still editing... and now its done

The base of the log must match the base of the exponent. You can use $2,10,e$… , but you need to stay consistent. For your first equation, you should use an equal sign $=$, or if you want to drop the little o a $\asymp$

@LPZ Did you mean the base of $\log$ in $H(c)$? Sorry I don't understand which other base should this one match to (be consistent with), but I tried putting $\log_2$ in $H(c)$ then it works

Yes, you wrote the asymptotics as $2^{…}$ so you need to use $\log_2$. Had you written it as $a^{…}$, you would have needed to use $\log_a$.

@LPZ Ah I see, thank you very much!

The problem is that the base of the logarithm don't match the base of the exponential expression.
Indeed, applying $\log_2$ to Stirling's approximation gives that
$$\log_2 (n!) = n \log_2 n - n \log_2 e + \frac12 \log_2 n + \frac12 (1 + \log_2 \pi) + R_1(n), \qquad R_1(n) \in O\left(\frac1n\right),$$
so
\begin{align*}
\log_2 {n \choose cn}
&= \log_2 \frac{n!}{(cn)! ((1 - c) n)!} \\
&= \log_2 (n!) - \log_2 [(cn)!] - \log_2[((1 - c) n)!] \\
&= n (-c \log_2 c - (1 - c) \log_2 c + R_2(n)), \qquad R_2(n) \in O\left(\frac{\log_2 n}{n}\right) . \\
\end{align*}
Denoting $H(c) := -c \log_2 c - (1 - c) \log_2 c$ and rearranging gives
$${n \choose cn} = 2^{n (H(c) + R_2(n))}$$
as desired. (In fact we discarded some terms in the approximation for $\log_2 {n \choose cn}$; keeping them would give an improved exponent $H(c)$.)
Remark The quantity $H(c)$ is just the Shannon entropy of a binomial random variable with probability $c$.
